# What are the guarantees for Apache Flume HDFS sink file writes?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, flume

Could somebody shed some light on what happens if the Flume agent gets killed in the middle of the HDFS file write (say using Avro format)? Will the file get corrupted and all events there lost?

I understand that there are transactions between different elements of the Flume data chain (source->channel->sink). But I believe that the HDFS files may stay open between consecutive channel->sink transactions (as .tmp). So if one transaction of say 100 events is successful (and the events are stored in a file, transaction committed) and the next one fails in the middle of the HDFS write could it be that the original 100 events from the first transaction are not readable (because the file corruption for instance?). How come Flume can assure that the original 100 events from the first transaction are not affected by this type of failure? Or maybe there is no guarantee there?

Answer (score 0):

If the Flume agent is killed in the middle of HDFS file write , the file won't get corrupted and there will be no data loss.

IF flume is writing to a file say FlumeData123456789.tmp when the flume agent is killed, then all the records written into that file  up till that point will remain intact and the file will be saved as FlumeData123456789.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how come the file will be renamed (I understand that that's the case)? In consecutive runs it might not even know that it has created this file with .tmp in some directory to which it might never return (i.e. due to a change in the data). I tested that and flume was always leaving this *.tmp file and starting a new one. As to the corruption I'm curious to understand where the guarantee  is coming from? Is this related to the specific type of writer or just in general to hdfs protocol?